# Adding scrollView to my player list in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, scrollview

I'm new with React Native and I'm trying to create an Android app in an Expo project, but I'm having issues with adding scroll view to the screen where I want the player names to be displayed.

This is the code for the screen:

*Previous Code*

```
return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <ImageBackground source={img} style={styles.fotofondo} resizeMode='cover'>
         <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Ingresar jugadores</Text>
           <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
           <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Nuevo jugador"
           value={newPlayer}
            onChangeText={(text) => setNewPlayer(text)}
         />
         <Button title="Agregar" color={"green"} onPress={handleAddPlayer} />
       </View>
       <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Lista de jugadores:</Text>
       <FlatList
         data={players}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
         renderItem={({ item }) => (
           <View style={styles.playerItem}>
             <View style={styles.playerInfo}>
               <Text style={styles.nombre}>{item}</Text>
             </View>
             <Button title="Eliminar" color={"red"} onPress={() => handleRemovePlayer(item)} />
          </View>
         )}
       />
       <Button title='Empezar juego' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Juego', { players })}/> 
     </View>
    </ImageBackground>

     <FlatList
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       renderItem={({ item }) => (
         <View>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
       )}
     />
     {/* <Button title='Empezar juego' onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Juego', { players })} /> */}
   </View>
 );
};``
```

The style names and text are in spanish, but what I want to know is how to add the scroll function.

I know that the flatlist is the main problem because I can't have FlatList and ScrollView. I wanted to know how can I display the player names with the delete button in the same format but add the scrollView.

Comment: I would recommend rewriting this component. Having two FlatLists and wanting to add a ScrollView on one screen is not ideal. In a web app, that would be ok, but not mobile. Rethink the workflow to offload some of the views to a different screen.